# label Taylor diagram with number by Python

Tags: python, label

My Python code here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.projections import PolarAxes
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.grid_finder as gf
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as fa


class TaylorDiagram(object):
  def __init__(self, STD ,fig=None, rect=111, label='_'):
    self.STD = STD
    tr = PolarAxes.PolarTransform()
    # Correlation labels
    rlocs = np.concatenate(((np.arange(11.0) / 10.0), [0.95, 0.99]))
    tlocs = np.arccos(rlocs) # Conversion to polar angles
    gl1 = gf.FixedLocator(tlocs) # Positions
    tf1 = gf.DictFormatter(dict(zip(tlocs, map(str, rlocs))))
    # Standard deviation axis extent
    self.smin = 0
    self.smax = 1.6 * self.STD
    gh = fa.GridHelperCurveLinear(tr,extremes=(0,(np.pi/2),self.smin,self.smax),grid_locator1=gl1,tick_formatter1=tf1,)
    if fig is None:
      fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fa.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=gh)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)
    # Angle axis
    ax.axis['top'].set_axis_direction('bottom')
    ax.axis['top'].label.set_text("Correlation coefficient")
    ax.axis['top'].toggle(ticklabels=True, label=True)
    ax.axis['top'].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('top')
    ax.axis['top'].label.set_axis_direction('top')
    # X axis
    ax.axis['left'].set_axis_direction('bottom')
    ax.axis['left'].label.set_text("Standard deviation")
    ax.axis['left'].toggle(ticklabels=True, label=True)
    ax.axis['left'].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('bottom')
    ax.axis['left'].label.set_axis_direction('bottom')
    # Y axis
    ax.axis['right'].set_axis_direction('top')
    ax.axis['right'].label.set_text("Standard deviation")
    ax.axis['right'].toggle(ticklabels=True, label=True)
    ax.axis['right'].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('left')
    ax.axis['right'].label.set_axis_direction('top')
    # Useless
    ax.axis['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    # Contours along standard deviations
    ax.grid()
    self._ax = ax # Graphical axes
    self.ax = ax.get_aux_axes(tr) # Polar coordinates
    # Add reference point and STD contour
    l , = self.ax.plot([0], self.STD, 'k*', ls='', ms=12, label=label)
    l1 , = self.ax.plot([0], self.STD, 'k*', ls='', ms=12, label=label)
    t = np.linspace(0, (np.pi / 2.0))
    t1 = np.linspace(0, (np.pi / 2.0))
    r = np.zeros_like(t) + self.STD
    r1 = np.zeros_like(t) + self.STD
    self.ax.plot(t, r, 'k--', label='_')
    # Collect sample points for latter use (e.g. legend)
    self.samplePoints = [l]
    self.samplePoints = [l1]
  def add_sample(self,STD,r,*args,**kwargs):
    l,= self.ax.plot(np.arccos(r), STD, *args, **kwargs) # (theta, radius)
    self.samplePoints.append(l)
    return l

  def add_sample(self,STD,r1,*args,**kwargs):
    l1,= self.ax.plot(np.arccos(r1), STD, *args, **kwargs) # (theta, radius)
    self.samplePoints.append(l1)
    return l1

  def add_contours(self,levels=5,**kwargs):
    rs, ts = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(self.smin, self.smax), np.linspace(0, (np.pi / 2.0)))
    RMSE=np.sqrt(np.power(self.STD, 2) + np.power(rs, 2) - (2.0 * self.STD * rs  *np.cos(ts)))
    contours = self.ax.contour(ts, rs, RMSE, levels, **kwargs)
    return contours

def srl(obsSTD, s, s1, r, r1, l, l1, fname):
  fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
  dia=TaylorDiagram(obsSTD, fig=fig, rect=111, label='ref')
  plt.clabel(dia.add_contours(colors='#808080'), inline=1, fontsize=10)
  srlc = zip(s, r, l)
  srlc1 = zip(s1, r1, l1)
   
  for i in srlc:
    dia.add_sample(i[0], i[1], label=i[2], marker='o',mec = 'red', mfc = 'none', mew=1.6)
  for i in srlc1:
    dia.add_sample(i[0], i[1], label=i[2], marker='^', mec = 'blue', mfc = 'none', mew=1.6)
  spl = [p.get_label() for p in dia.samplePoints]
  fig.legend(dia.samplePoints, spl, numpoints=1, prop=dict(size='small'), loc=[0.7,0.3])
  plt.show()

obsSTD = 1

s = [1.275412605,1.391302157,1.424314937]
s1 = [0.980035327,0.997244197, 1.003002031]
r = [0.572272,0.533529,0.477572]
r1 = [0.82,0.72,0.8]

l = ['A', 'B','C']
l1 = ['A', 'B','C']

fname = 'TaylorDiagram.jpg'
srl(obsSTD, s, s1, r, r1, l,l1, fname)
```

And give a result that: [taylor_dig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61AqW.png) that the red is before processing, the blue for after one. How could I label the position of A, B, C models as 1,2,3 (enumerate) with the position of before and after processing as well as legends without repeating?

Comment: For the record, this code is a strong derivative of https://gist.github.com/ycopin/3342888. Please cite https://zenodo.org/record/5548061 as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the code it works with me. However I am wondering how can I add the bias expressed in coloured points with colorbar. As in the following example: https://github.com/PeterRochford/SkillMetrics/blob/master/Examples/taylor11_example.png

Comment: @YannickCopin What is the best way to cite that page? Should I add a mention of it in the .py file after I have downloaded it?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I think a link either to the original page (https://gist.github.com/ycopin/3342888) or to the zenodo one (https://zenodo.org/record/5548061) would be nice!